# try catch loop issue

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch, do-while

In the following code I want the program to loop via `try catch` to allow user to re-enter answer for first addition if they gave an invalid input (i.e letter instead of int). Currently the code displays catch statement but also goes on through the program and also displays the `System.out.println("Sorry incorrect, please guess again");` from if else statement which I don't want. Can someone help me fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
    public static void add() {

        // Setting up random
        Random random = new Random();

        // Declaring Integers
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int result;
        int input;
        input = 0;
        // Declaring boolean for userAnswer (Defaulted to false)
        boolean correctAnswer = false;
        do {
            // Create two random numbers between 1 and 100
            num1 = random.nextInt(100);
            num1++;
            num2 = random.nextInt(100);
            num2++;

        do{ 
            // Displaying numbers for user and getting user input for answer
            System.out.println("Adding numbers...");
            System.out.printf("What is: %d + %d? Please enter answer below",
                    num1, num2);
            result = num1 + num2;

                try {
                    input = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Print error message
                    System.out.println("Invalid number entered for addition...");
                    // flush scanner
                    scanner.next();
                    correctAnswer = false;
                }
        }while(correctAnswer=false);

            // Line break for code clarity
            System.out.println();

            // if else statement to determine if answer is correct
            if (result == input) {

                System.out.println("Well done, you guessed corectly!");
                correctAnswer = true;
            } else {

                System.out.println("Sorry incorrect, please guess again");
                correctAnswer=false;
            }
        } while (!correctAnswer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
while(correctAnswer=false)
```

You need

```
while(correctAnswer==false)
```

What you have is an assignment of `false` to `correctAnswer` - an expression that is always `false`, so the loop never continues. A more common way of writing `a==false` is `!a`, so I would correct the loop condition to

```
while(!correctAnswer)
```

which reads more "fluently".

Of course now you need to set `correctAnswer = true` at the top of your loop to avoid infinite iterations.

Comment: This fixes the first part, but changing `while(correctAnswer=false)` with `while(correctAnswer==false)` will cause an endless loop as `correctAnswer` is never changed to `true` in the while

Comment: Thanks this has fixed my issue! What exactly do you mean by infinite iterations? I see that the code works but unsure of exactly how?

Comment: @RNI2013 Since you never set `correctAnswer` to `true`, you wouldn't be able to exit the inner `do` / `while` loop. You should add `correctAnswer = true;` at the top of the loop to fix this problem.

Comment: Yeah got it fixed thank you, i realise now about the infinite loops!